# Double integral-Split region into subregions

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to write the following consecutive intergrals as an intergral on a specific region $D$, that is of type 2 ($D=\{(x,y) \mid h_1(y)\leq x\leq h_2(y), c\leq y\leq d\}$) but not of type 1 ($D=\{(x,y) \mid a\leq x\leq b, g_1(x)\leq y\leq g_2(x)\}$). I want to split $D$ into two subregions of type 1 and then reverse the order of integrals using the Fubini formulas:

$\int_{-1}^1\left (\int_{-2|y|}^{|y|}f(x,y)dx\right )dy$.

We have that $-2|y|\leq x\leq |y|$ and $-1\leq y\leq 1$. Therefore the region of type 2 is $D=\{(x,y)\mid 2|y|\leq x\leq |y|, -1\leq y\leq 1\}$.

How can we split $D$ into two subregions of type 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kcuzjlnksx) (where the two colours intersect):

[image]

You can split it into four regions of type $1$:

- $\left\{(x,y) \middle| -2 \le x \le 0, -1 \le y \le \dfrac12x \right\}$
- $\left\{(x,y) \middle| -2 \le x \le 0, -\dfrac12x \le y \le 1 \right\}$
- $\left\{(x,y) \middle| 0 \le x \le 1, -1 \le y \le -x \right\}$
- $\left\{(x,y) \middle| 0 \le x \le 1, x \le y \le 1 \right\}$